# Is there any way to finitely represent all the information in pi?

Tags: pi, number-systems

Of course, we can represent it as 10 in base pi but that won't be much useful. Think of pi as a length from 0 to some unique point on the real line. A length which cannot be finitely expressed in any integer base system because integer base systems are all about rationals while pi is inherently irrational. It's a no-brainer why all representations of pi have been infinite. It's because we've chosen natural numbers to study this more complex phenomenon known as pi. Base systems are all about strings of natural numbers. Pi goes beyound natural numbers.So how about we change the system? Is there any system you know of where pi can be represented finitely?

UPDATE More specifically, Do you know of any number system (besides base pi, base root pi, etc) in which pi can be represented finitely?  It need not be a base-system.

Also, the current answer by @HenningMakholm is technically a finite representation of pi, but I don't think it qualifies as a number system.

Comment: @Peter I addressed that in the very first sentence of my post. It's like we know only two ways to represent pi. One way using strings of natural numbers, which is infinite, can never give us the complete information. In the other way, like in base pi or radians, we make pi itself the unit and that's just self-referential, doesn't tell us how much pi is exactly.

Comment: Please clarify "represent" ! Do you consider $\pi$ or some inifnite sum with value $\pi$ as a finite "representation" ? Sorry, that I missed somehow the statement at the beginning.

Comment: @Peter I don't consider using pi itself or some other version of it like pi/2, root pi as finite representation. And I don't consider Infinite sums as finite representation because those are infinite.

Comment: @RyderRude: The series is described by finitely many symbols from a finite alphabet. How can you _not_ consider that to be a finite representation?

Comment: What do you say about $\pi = 4 \;\arctan(1)?$

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah, all the information is within that sum. But to extract the full information, you have to do that sum which is an infinite process. I think the problem with infinite sums is that they are also about summing RATIONAL numbers, that's why they have to be infinite. Pi is inherently beyound rationals.

Comment: @RyderRude If I understand right what you mean with "finite representation", there is none (which you already mentioned yourself). But this problem also arises with $\sqrt{2}$, for example.

Comment: @RyderRude: If you want to get an infinite amount of information (bits?) out of the representation you want, but _do not_ want to spend an unbounded amount of effort to extract that information, then I think your desire is _inherently unreasonable_.

Comment: @gammatester Does that even tell us how big the number is? That's just another version of the definition of pi=circumference/diameter

Comment: @HenningMakholm But pi is not an infinite amount of information. It's a finite length just as normal as the length between 0 and 3. It's the tools that we used to get to it which make it look infinite. Those tools can never get there. You can never finitely represent how big one third is if you use base 10 as your tool. Base 12 makes 1/3 seem normal.

Comment: @RyderRude You want full information about all the digits, not just the point where $\pi$ lies ont the real line, or did I completely misunderstand the question ? By the way, since $1/3$ is rational, we can fully describe the decimal expansion in a finite way (namely with the period)

Comment: @RyderRude: If you accept that $\pi$ is not an infinite amount of information (which I would agree with), then I don't understand what your objection to representing that finite amount of information as a series is.

Comment: @Peter Have people tried to think of number representations that don't rely on bases? Are you aware of any of those systems? People could just develop new basic constant symbols and new rules followed by them and see if the information within irrationals can be finitely represented by those symbols.

Comment: Since $\pi$ is transcendental it cannot be represented by a finite expression
$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$ with rational $a_k$. Please specify more exactly what you 
mean with *finitely representing* a number.

Comment: @gammatester I agree. It is hard to decide what the author allows and does not allow to be a "finite representation"

Comment: @RyderRude "Information" is not a very precise word either. What do you mean with "$\pi$ contains only finite many information" ? I would not agree to that when we mean the decimal expansion.

Comment: @Peter I want some number system which treats all the points on the number line as equal. Our number systems starts with 9 integer symbols and then strings of those symbols are used to measure every number. But it is later found that these symbols can never completely represent irrationals. Why can't we use a system which measures pi or root 2 as simply as it measures 2,3,4,1/2...

Comment: @RyderRude: Yes, people have thought of number representation that don't depend on bases -- such as in the (currently only) answer to this question. You have subsequently decreed that those systems don't count. At this point it appears to be clear that no matter what anyone answers you will find a way to move the goalposts so the answer somehow doesn't count.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're answer is technically a finite representation but the sum it represents is infinite. I think the underlying problem is that it's just a sum of rational numbers. That's why it has to be an infinite sum . We 're always trying to build irrational numbers off rational numbers.

Comment: @Peter Is the question clear in the update?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Is the question  clear in the update?

Comment: @RyderRude: No -- it remains open for you to claim that whatever anyone proposes does not qualify as a "number system" for you.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It doesn't. A number system is well defined. From wikipedia -"A numeral system (or system of numeration) is a writing system for expressing numbers; that is, a mathematical notation for representing numbers of a $given \: set$, using digits or other symbols in a consistent manner." Replace the 'given set' in this definition with the set of reals (for my requirement). A number system should also be able to represent other numbers of the set in a similar way. Yours is a formula only for representing pi.

Comment: @RyderRude: If you can distort that definition to mean that the formalism the formula in my answer is written in is not a "number system", you can probably distort it in any other way you please, too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm What did I distort about that definition? I just chose a set for the definition. Your answer is  a formula only for representing pi. A number system should also be able to represent other numbers of a given set .

Comment: @RyderRude: There are plenty of other numbers that can be represented in the same formalism -- in fact I'll challenge you to name any concrete real number that _can't_. You have apparently decided that any formalism that can represent an infinite series cannot be a "number system", on no consistent grounds that I can discern from your writings.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Can your number system represent other numbers besides pi? Because that's what number systems do according to their official definition.

Comment: @RyderRude:Please name any number that you think _can't_ be represented in the notation I'm using.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I've just found my last requirement. The representation must not contain infinity or any indication of carrying out an algorithm forever. Your summation contains the infinity symbol. Tell me a number system which satisfies these requirements and I promise I'll not object further. As a side note, was the representation of 5 in your number system supposed to be 1+1+1+1+1?

Comment: @RyderRude: Just replace the $\infty$ symbol with a happy face and you're all set. The algorithm terminates in a finite time always. And yes, $1+1+1+1+1$ is a perfectly good representation of five in standard mathematical notation. So is $5$, by the way.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The happy face is still infinity so your anwer doesn't satisfy all requirements. Good day.

Comment: @RyderRude: You've got it the wrong way aroung. _Both_ the happy face and the $\infty$ symbol are just ink. There's nothing infinite about ink. Your requirements are unreasonable, badly specfied and designed to let you reject any answer anyone proposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\pi$ can be represented by a finite formula in standard mathematical notation, such as:
$$ \pi = 4 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} $$
This contains all information there is to get about the value of $\pi$.

(This formula, known as the [Leibniz series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80), has the primary benefit that it is short to write down. It converges infeasibly slowly in practice, but we can use it to prove that other, longer but more efficient, formulas describe the same number).

---

More precisely, this formula gives you a concrete procedure for deciding, for each rational number and *in finite time*, whether your rational number is smaller or larger than $\pi$. Simply start summing the series, and as soon as you reach a point where the difference between the partial sum so far and your target rational is *smaller than* the next term in the series, you're done.

(That this works depends on the fact that the series is an absolutely decreasing alternating series, *and* that your target rational is not $\pi$ itself. The latter is because we know $\pi$ is not rational, which is not obvious but definitely known).